# Android: new Locale("sv") crashing me app

Tags: android

The following WORKS:

```
Configuration newConfig = new Configuration();
newConfig.locale = Locale.US;
//newConfig.locale = new Locale("sv"); // swedish
onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
```

The following CRASHES my app:

```
Configuration newConfig = new Configuration();
//newConfig.locale = Locale.US;
newConfig.locale = new Locale("sv"); // swedish
onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
```

I have the following values folders:

```
values-en-rUS/strings.xml
values-sv/strings.xml
```

Both strings.xml include the exact same text.

I suspect I am either naming my values folder incorrect or the "sv" is incorrect.

Here is the logcat, I'm telling you it won't help you...

```
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at se.busarama.app.fragment.FragmentRight.onCreateView(FragmentRight.java:36)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    ... 21 more
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3374)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3293)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:451)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:242)
06-05 21:52:07.933: E/AndroidRuntime(30944):    ... 24 more
```

Comment: any exception logged in logcat?

Comment: Exception has to do with an xml failing to inflate, it's due to a @string/some_string not being found. I am writing something wrong in the code posted.

Comment: Post the logcat please.

Comment: I suspect I am naming either my values folder incorrect or Sweden does not have "sv"

Comment: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1 custom values?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13721748/2791708) could help

Comment: @MarcoAcierno the dimens.xml file was not in the values folder(it was in the values-en folder), now it works! (wonder what the dimens.xml file does...)

Comment: It's because when he have a specific locate he will search for values-YOUR_LOCATE and if not exists will search inside values (without locate, default.) So it was unable to search the dimension